# How to set callback url in Facebook realtime updates using nodejs

Tags: facebook, node.js

Is there any way that I can do realtime update from Facebook in localhost and if it can not how to set the callback url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using "passport" for authentication in node.js...

you can set the call back url as follows.....

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy(
{
            clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
            clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
            callbackURL: "your url"
}
```

Comment: I can get authentication through oauth and the callbackURL is different from the URL in realtime update.